# How to disabled past days selection in p-calender using primeng?

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using primeng p-calender
I have the requirement that not to send past dates to the API,

So I want to disable past dates selection

If anyone knows please, comment

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation ref: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

in your .html

`<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="dateValue" [minDate]="yesterday " [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>`

via ts

```
var today = new Date();
let yesterday = new Date($today);
yesterday.setDate($today.getDate() - 1);
```

Comment: you just saved me!!